# Firebase Crash Reporting iOS - Unreadable Crashes - Upload Symbol Files?

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I'm trying to integrate Firebase Crash reporting for my iOS app. I am using Xcode 8.1, Swift 3 and the latest Firebase Crash reporting version as of 29/11/16.

I have installed Firebase Crash reporting via Cocoapods and have I gone through the limited setup guide from the documentation shown below where I added a run script with my Google App ID and the path to my Google Crash Key son file (Service account)

1. Replace this with the GOOGLE_APP_ID from your GoogleService-Info.plist file

   GOOGLE_APP_ID=1:my:app:id
2. Replace the /Path/To/ServiceAccount.json with the path to the key you just downloaded

   ```
   "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "/Path/To/ServiceAccount.json"
   ```

I am not sure if I have implemented the second step correctly. I did this

```
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/******/GoogleCrashKey.json"
```

The problem I have is that my app crash reports are pretty unreadable. I believe I either need to upload a symbol file or I have got the second step wrong.

[image: Unreadable Firebase Crash]

How would I upload the symbol files for crash reporting. I get this instruction when pressing the upload symbol file option in the Firebase Crash reporting console. However I am unsure how to implement it.

1: Using the command line, navigate to your Xcode project folder and run the following:

```
    ./Pods/FirebaseCrash/batch-upload  < service-account-file >  my_UUID
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Comment: Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: what makes your reports unreadable? can you give an example?

Comment: Hi @martin , I just edited my question now and included an image of the Crash Reports. I am forcing a crash using fatalError() in appDelegate

Comment: ok, I see your example screenshot now. Did you add custom log messages like they suggest? from the firebase doc:FIRCrashMessage("Cause Crash button clicked")
fatalError()

Comment: No I didn't add custom log messages. I assumed that they weren't necessary in order to get readable crashes in Firebase. I have just tried that now and I am waiting for the report.

Comment: didn't even receive the message - actually still not sure if I have got step 2 wrong or I need to upload the symbol files.

Comment: I don't know... I'm giving it a try but need to install some updates. Did you try it on a completely new project (new in xcode and firebase) and follow the steps exactly?

Comment: Good idea. Will try that out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was making a mistake when I was trying to implement the second step. I had the Speech marks in the wrong place and had the whole file path as a string :(.

instead of doing this:

```
    "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}/******/GoogleCrashKey.json"
```

I changed it to this:

```
     "${PODS_ROOT}"/FirebaseCrash/upload-sym "${SRCROOT}" /******/GoogleCrashKey.json"
```

My crash report now looks like the following:

[image: Correct Firebase Crash Report Structure]

Thanks for the help Martin. Much appreciated.

Comment: Please do you see concrete row on the orange highlighted line?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the Firebase log - a bunch of unreadable information. After adding the symbol file, it worked fine.

Just in case someone is wondering how to add the symbol file, [here is the link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/ios#upload_symbol_files).